# model name to controller name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I get the controller name out of the object if I don't know what the object is?

I am trying to do:

```
object.class.tableize
```

but Rails says:

```
undefined method `tableize' for #<Class:0xb6f8ee20>
```

I tried adding demodulize with same result.

thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
object.class.to_s.tableize
```

Answer (score 1):

For semantic reasons, you might want to do:

```
object.class.name #=> 'FooBar'
```

You can also use tableize with this sequence, like so:

```
object.class.name.tableize #=> 'foo_bars'
```

I prefer it that way due to readability.

As well, note that `tableize` also does pluralization. If unwanted use `underscore`.

Hope it helps anyone, even if it's an old thread :)